# No results searching custom post type in admin panel

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, search

So I have a custom post type `action` and when I search in the admin panel I don't get any results. I think I figured out why, but not sure how to fix it. When I enter a search term and then click "Search actions" it takes me to this url:

```
http://localhost/wp-admin/edit.php?s=foobaz&post_status=all&post_type=action&action=-1&m=0&paged=1&mode=list&action2=-1
```

It shows no results, and I see why, but I don't understand where all those extra query vars are coming from? I disabled all plugins, emptied out my `functions.php` and still it takes me there, showing no results.

I can make it work if I manually change the url to:

```
http://localhost/wp-admin/edit.php?s=foobaz&post_status=all&post_type=action
```

The above will show any actions containing "foobaz".

Any ideas where do I begin to fix this?

Comment: I'll guess that you can't name your post type `action`, that's a query string var used by core in various contexts. Try renaming your post type slug to something else.

Comment: @Milo, I was trying that just now, but I would have to edit my database to get all actions transferred to the new pots type, will report back

Comment: @Milo, Yup, that was it! Feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this case is the name of the post type, `action`. WordPress core uses the query var `action` for its own purposes, so this has created a conflict somewhere within the code. The solution is to rename the post type to something unique to remove the conflict.